# Неизвестное выражение stream

Tags: java

Читал всякие примеры по java и наткнулся на такой вот код:

```java
public List<String> list() {
        return model.stream()
                .map(User::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Может кто-нибудь объяснить что тут вообще происходит, как я понял идёт возврат списка имён класса User или что-то другое? Где об этом всём можно почитать, посмотреть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это `Stream API`. Оно предназначено для работы со структурами данных, в основном с коллекциями и массивами.

Краткая выжимка:

> Stream — это объект для универсальной работы с данными. Мы указываем,
>   какие операции хотим провести, при этом не заботясь о деталях
>   реализации. Например, взять элементы из списка сотрудников, выбрать
>   тех, кто младше 40 лет, отсортировать по фамилии и поместить в новый
>   список.

Не знаю, какой тип у `model`, но предположу, что `List`. В данном примере создается стрим из экземпляров `User` хранящихся в листе - `model.stream()`.

Потом созданный стрим "мапиться" - изменяется на другой стрим с другими значениями с помощью `map`.

> Метод `map` применяет функцию к каждому элементу и затем возвращает
>   стрим, в котором элементами будут результаты функции.

Метод `map` принимает лямбда выражение(которое соответствует интерфейсу `Function`) и возвращает значение, которое получается после применения выражения к каждому элементу стрима. К каждому элементу стрима(т.е. к экземплярам `User`) применяется `User.getName()`, и вместо стрима с `User` получается стрим из переменных `name` `User`.

После этого стрим "собирается в список" с помощью `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

> С его помощью можно собрать все элементы в список, множество или
>   другую коллекцию, сгруппировать элементы по какому-нибудь критерию,
>   объединить всё в строку и т.д.

На самом деле, у вас в примере очень простой стрим, бывают намного сложнее. Чтобы понять как работают стримы советую прочитать книги по функциональной Java, или в крайнем случае циклы статей по стримам, например [этот](https://annimon.com/article/2778) или [этот](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/java-8-uchebnik/). Также есть хороший [мини-справочник по Stream API](https://habr.com/ru/company/luxoft/blog/270383/), но его будет сложно понять если не знаком со стримами.

В итоге из коллекции `[User1, User2, User3]` получится коллекция `["Вася", "Петя", "Вова"]`.

Comment: Всё классно, спасибо, ток вопрос к знатоку: лямбда выражение - это как бы ссылка на какой-то метод?

Comment: @ImmRaytal нет, лямбда выражение это скорее анонимный класс с одним методом. Т.е., `x->x+1` - это лямбда выражение. Вообще, синтаксис у него такой: `(параметры принимаемые методом) -> {тело метода}`. Если у лямбды всего один параметр и одно действие(как выше), то можно писать без скобок. Т.е., это аналог этому -`(x) -> {return x+1}` . Вот пример большой лямбды: `(x, y, z) -> {x = y+z; z=x+y; y = x+z; return y;}`. Лямбда в ответе, про которую вы спросили, это тоже укроченный вариант. Полная лямбда будет такая: `x -> x.getName` Т.е она принимает `User` в `x`, потом применяет к нему метод getName